# Error 'OracleInternal.Common.ODTSettings.m_bUseLongIdentifiers' While adding migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I add a code-first EF migration, I get the following error:

**Field not found: 'OracleInternal.Common.ODTSettings.m_bUseLongIdentifiers'.**

and the migration is not created.

I'm targeting Oracle 12c and verified my connection strings and all the configuration.
The same configuration works perfectly in another project.

Answer (score 10):

Apparently the latest stable ODP.net drivers has a bug, you need to down grade your ODP.net drivers to the previous stable version.

Try the following packages;

> Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess -**Version 12.1.22**
>
> Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework -**Version 12.1.22**